# Where we can see the total downloads of our iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I have submitted my two applications in AppStore. It got approved now and showing in AppStore. If i want to see how many downloads is going on per day, where i can go and see? Can i use my developer account to see or any other place is there?

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a great tool used to parse the HORRIBLE sales reports from Apple.  It is called [AppViz](http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/) and has many goodies such as trends, graphs and rankings… It is really miles ahead of what Apple has provided.

Comment: You just made life a lot easier! Thanks for this discovery. Quick doubt: can AppViz only show for the past 14 days from the date of install?

Comment: It gets its data by scanning gthe sales reports from Apple. You can import older reports though, but it can't magically produce the ones that are not on iTunes connect.

Comment: Sorry im kinda new and I didn't know they dont give old reports. I would be great if it magically produce though!

Comment: Bro, the link is dead. Any alternative site?

Comment: AppViz went out of business and abandoned all of their users.

Comment: Yes out of business, but not abandoned. They worked hard to ease the pain: http://blog.appviz.com/2014/11/appviz-is-shutting-down/

Answer (score 1):

It's in [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/)

Comment: thank you. I hope it should be under Sales/Trend Reports in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Ok. I could able to go to Transaction Reports and see the daily basis table though my account in iTunes Connect. Which one shows about downloads in this table? Is that "Units" column is the one does show about total downloads?

Comment: @Getsy There is no "total" in iTunes Connect i'm afraid. I've yet to see it. ( Or so i beleive )

Answer (score 1):

You can view sales by day, week, month and year by clicking the date in the top right hand corner of the Sales and Trends report for your app in iTunes Connect.

it seems to go back a few years, so should show you the figures you need

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something to replace AppViz now that they went cloud + subscription. I found [AppWage](http://appwage.com) which is in beta and it seems to work ok so far. I've had a few stability issues, but hey for a free its great.

Comment: FYI, I'm the developer of AppWage and its now open source. https://github.com/hankinsoft/AppWage

Answer (score 0):

There is another great tool called **Distimo**  http://www.distimo.com/; it is online and you can add all your store accounts (not only iOS). You have lots of statistics and it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.
[image]